# IndexError: index 200 is out of bounds for axix 0 with size 200

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code in pycharm 2017.2. After runing there is an indexerror like this:
[indexerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGiPa.png)

indexerror: index 200 is out of bounds for axix 0 with size 200.

It seems like problem is happening in code here.

I have no idea what's going on.

Can anyone help me :)

from scipy import misc
    import math

```
# Returns string of 12-bit color at row x, column y of image
def get_color_bits(im, x, y):
    # convert color components to byte string and slice needed upper bits
    b = format(im[y][x][0], 'b').zfill(8)
    rx = b[0:4]
    b = format(im[y][x][1], 'b').zfill(8)
    gx = b[0:4]
    b = format(im[y][x][2], 'b').zfill(8)
    bx = b[0:4]

    # return concatination of RGB bits
    return str(rx+gx+bx)
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of your array im and what values are you passing as x and y?

Comment: please update your question to include what is passed to the function, ideally some code that can be executed that demonstrates the question.